# Can't go to next step after going back using vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm using [vee-validate v3](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3) to validate a multi step form then call axios. I use `handleSubmit` and added `ValidationObserver` with unique keys for each step. Now my issue is after moving to the next step and then going back to step 1, the next button is not firing even if there's no field errors found.

Here's the code structure: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-6hrh4?file=/src/Demo.vue

Note:

- the currentStep on my real project is from local storage.
- The sample code is just the structure since the actual fields are too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<button>` placed inside a `<form>` element defaults to `type="submit"`.

Which means in any `<form>` you need to call `preventDefault()` on a `<button>` `click` if you don't want the form submitted.

Changing `@click` into `@click.prevent` [fixes the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-vxjdo?file=/src/Demo.vue) (because the form is no longer submitted when clicking <kbd>Previous</kbd>, therefore `currentStep` is no longer increased by `1` right after it is decreased by the `@click` expression - making it look like nothing happened. In fact, both the `@click` expression and the `onSubmit` get executed if you don't use `.prevent` modifier).

---

As an alternative, you can change the `<button>` into an anchor:

```
<a href class="btn" @click="currentStep--" v-text="Previous" />
```

although I'd personally go with preventing default.

Comment: i think it's the same as `<form @submit.prevent="">` ?

Comment: @claudios, not really. preventing the `click` on that button prevents the code from `onSubmit` to be executed when the button is pressed. Whereas using `@submit.prevent` on the form doesn't (it only prevents the page being reloaded upon submission, which is default HTML forms behavior because typically a `<form>` would send the request to the backend and reload the page - or load whatever `action` param on `<form>` points to). Whenever you assume something works in some way, it's wise to test if it actually does.

Comment: yea you're right. it worked in my example using prevent or anchor tag. But in my actual code got no luck. this is weird I think I miss something not sure what.

Comment: The only way I could help further would be if you added enough from what you call "actual code" to the sandbox, until you repro and I could see what's wrong. Side note: you don't need luck for coding. Only method and patience.

Comment: Oh figured it out what causing the issue on my end. It's because of my custom file uploader. Thanks by the way